# Loading font with priority

Tags: javascript, java, css, jsp

I am working on commercial application where I want to optimizes performance of certain web page. I have done all the required changes but couldn't set the priority of test.fonts.css to High.

jsp page code

```
<%@ taglib prefix="mag" uri="mag-custom-taglib"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>

<mag:cache-controlled-link href="/order/genome-database/assets/core/dist/fonts/test.fonts.css"/>
```

cache-controlled-link tag is defined in its own Tag Library Descriptor File

```
 <tag>
        <name>cache-controlled-link</name>
        <tagclass>core.jsp.tag.CacheControlledLink</tagclass>
        <attribute>
            <name>showVersion</name>
            <required>false</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>showTimestamp</name>
            <required>false</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>href</name>
            <required>true</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
    </tag>
```

and tagclass i.e. CacheControlledLink is a java file

```
public class CacheControlledLink extends CacheControlledAsset {

    protected String href;

    @Override
    public int doStartTag() throws JspException {
        try {

            JspWriter out = pageContext.getOut();

            String href = buildUrlToResource();

            out.print("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"");
            out.print(href);
            out.println("\"/>");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Unable to write CacheControlledLink tag to jsp:", e);
        }
        return SKIP_BODY;
    }

    public void setHref(String href) {
        this.href = href;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getUri() {
        return href;
    }
}
```

I know that to set priority I have to use rel="preload" but I dont know how to set that property for target href. I tried to format href to add "rel= "preload" but got "jasperexception - invalid for tag according to TLD"

what is the best way to set priority?

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you want to set an extra attribute `rel` when you use the `<mag:cache-controlled-link` tag in your JSP. But the tag implementation and descriptor do not declare that attribute; you'd need to change the descriptor and implementation to support that attribute and then to change the output to include that "rel" attribute on the `<link>` that it generates.

Comment: Yes I am doing that right now but my is it possible to do it for a single href as cache-controlled-link is being used throughout the application for different href.